# MapBox JS Gl: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am writing a script to retrieve a list of all the cities in the user's current view/area. For example, if the user is zoomed into the following area:

[image]

The following cities are returned: Westminster, Santa Ana, Orange, Villa Park, Huntington Beach, Cosa Mesa, Irvine, Newport Beach.

I am trying to use MapBox's `queryRenderedFeatures` function to get the list of cities. I'm passing in the boundary box of the user's zoomed in area and a list of the layers (just cities) as parameters, following this example:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures-around-point/

Below is my code:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
                style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
            });
var canvas = map.getCanvasContainer();
var bbox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var transformedBBox = [[bbox.left, bbox.top], [bbox.right, bbox.bottom]];

// Retrieve the cities within the user's current area;
var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(bbox, {layers: ['cities']});
```

But I receive the following error on the last line (when I'm trying to retrieve the features):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Comment: No clue, i would just test with `map.on('click'` and `bbox = [[e.point.x - 5, e.point.y - 5], [e.point.x + 5, e.point.y + 5]];`  so like in the exampe, to reduce the number of potential causes.... maybe it needs some time to load the features?

Comment: mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11 doesn't have "cities" layer. How are you adding it?

Comment: Can you put your full error stack?

Comment: @AnatolySukhanov I haven't added a cities dataset, I assumed MapBox would have a pre-defined cities dataset. Does MapBox have a way to automatically add all the cities in the user's current area to the map as a layer?